# textStatus error in API REST

Tags: ajax, rest

I make a request to a REST web url API, which answers an error in the textStatus field, but when I look at the response I have it as 200, what could be happening?

```
 $.post( "https://page/Api/SolicitudesAbis", {
                                                          "IdCliente": 23,
                                                          "IdConvenioAutenticacion": "759A28EB-8E51-4A3D-8681-F7E6F23088A6",
                                                          "TipoDocumentoCandidato": "CC",
                                                          "Candidato": "1076646338",
                                                          "IdMaquina": "",
                                                          "CodigoOficina": "Oficina 1",
                                                          "IdProducto": 1,
                                                          "IdSolicitudCliente": "1",
                                                          "TiempoValidez": 1,
                                                          "TipoIdentidadMaquina": 3,
                                                          "UsuarioCreacion": "jneira",
                                                          "ProcesoCliente": 0
                                                        }
        .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
            alert("Done");        
        })
        .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            alert("Fail " + textStatus);        
});
```

Comment: What specifically the error is?

Comment: Hi Carl, the error is that it does not enter the DONE function, because the request is made and answer has status code 200, and it leaves is what is in FAIL.

Comment: And what would be the error message? You said, it falls back to "fail". And your fail has textStatus right.. What is the message?

Comment: the message that has the textStatus of the fail function says:"error", but I see that the request code is 200, I don't know why it tells me error.